# Capture contentDocument for svg object in selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, selenium

I'm trying to automate test for svg images which is rendered in a web application.

The html looks like-

```
<object class="svgcanvas" type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"><h4>Error     loading SVG file</h4>
   #document
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-    highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" viewBox="0 0 1188 840" xml:space="preserve">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1188" height="840" style="stroke:none;     fill:white"/>
      <circle cx="20" cy="830" r="0.144857" style="stroke:#E50033; stroke-    width:0.339429"/>
      <g id="XMP_1" style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.339429">
        <path d="M554 401L641 401" style="stroke:#0000FF; stroke-dasharray: 3.5640  3.5640  3.5640  3.5640"/>
      </g>
</object>
```

I tried to get the svg object using the below code but svgElement throws the following error:

> '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)svgElement).Displayed' threw an exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException'

```
IWebElement objectTag =  _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("object.svgcanvas"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver;
string findingSVG = "return arguments[0].contentDocument;";
var svgElement = js.ExecuteScript(findingSVG, objectTag);
```

So, is there a way to test page that have SVG embedded in the object tag?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Stale element usually means that after you found the element and before calling any action on that object the page reloaded/changed. Make sure the page is loaded and all requests are done.

Comment: You need a way to make sure that the SVG and the main DOM are loaded before you start trying to manipulate that SVG.  Google (or StartPage): selenium wait for page to load javascript

Comment: Is the exception thrown on a line of `isDisplayed()`? Is the `<object>` inside a frame?

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to get the `contentDocument` for the `<object>` tag which [returns a Document object from a frame](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp), so it's not supposed to work.

The `<object>` tag is probably inside a `<frame>` so try switching to the content in the frame that contains the `<svg>` and then find your element:

```
_webDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
_webDriver.switchTo().Frame("YourFrameName");

IWebElement svgElementInsideFrame =  _webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("svg"));
```

Comment: using Iframe I am able to get it done .but the problem here is Iframe is not being used to render the object tag where svg content embedded. in javscript i am able to get contentDocument of object tag but when i excute the same script using selenium its not working.

Comment: Do you have an example URL? On what selenium command is the exception thrown?

Comment: sorry ,I don't have any example url. but i am getting above mentioned the exception .